# Can I use @WithMockUser with KotlinTest?

Tags: spring, kotlin, kotlintest

I am trying to use an annotation similar to `@WithMockUser` in KotlinTest. I have added the annotation to my spec, but it does not seem to work. I'm trying to write my own listener as well, but it does not seem to work, as I cannot get any annotation information from the Spec class. Is it possible to use a construct like `@WithMockUser`? The reason I'm not using the pre-existing annotation is that my user needs additional information that comes from the token.

**Example**

```
@WithGebruiker
    "GraphQL" should {
        "return data with valid query" {
            // test here
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's `WithGebruiker`?

Comment: `WithGebruiker` is WithUser.

Comment: KotlinTest has no knowledge of arbitrary mocking annotations.